# Is there any jQuery plugin for Hijri calendars?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, calendar, hijri

I wonder if there is any jQuery DatePicker plugin for Hijri calendars?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use from [jQuery Calendars](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) by Keith Wood or [Algerian Hijri Calendar](http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.calendars-ar-DZ.js) specifically.

Comment: Here is the script to include as well [islamic-ar.js](http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.calendars.islamic-ar.js)

Comment: How can I do a datepicker?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ummalqura file (jquery.calendars.ummalqura.js) to show the hijri calendar, go to this [link](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) and download the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There's one from ZulNs that displays Hijri dates and provides conversions as well. Might serve your purpose.
https://zulns.github.io/libs/calendar-api-doc.html