# calendar that display date in hijri date format

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, datepicker

I need any calendar which display hijri dates.

For example, if the date is 20/05/2014 then it will display  21/7/1435 in hijri date format.
I have tried:
[jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

In arabic mode but its not displaying the dates in hijri format. Example of the hijri date format I found on following link.

Example link : [Example](http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php?mode=ger-hij&day=20&month=5&year=2014&date_result=1)

Only the navigation and the titles are in hijri.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the region in your script:

```
$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "your_region" ] );
```

**Edit**

Then read this questione: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049315/is-there-any-jquery-plugin-for-hijri-calendar) I hope it is usefull to you

Comment: hi Teo, i have tried this $.datepicker.regional['ar'] but "date format" is not in hijri, i have seen jquery localization, i need this, when i select date 20/05/2014 then date is displayed like  21/7/1435