# Hijri dates integration with jQuery UI datepicker tool

Tags: calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker, hijri

I have been using jQuery UI datepicker tool, it works fine, but now i want to integrate Hijri calendar in it instead of default gregorian calendar

I saw a localization option in detailed options, it has an Arabic option, but it's not showing up Hijri dates

is there any external plugins which i can integrate with datepicker tool which would support Hijri calendar

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any jQuery plugin for Hijri calendars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049315/is-there-any-jquery-plugin-for-hijri-calendars)